# Swap 100% Utilized

Tags: linux

I see the following output:

```
[root@Dummy ~]# free -mt
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3820       3784         36          0          9       2847
-/+ buffers/cache:        927       2893
Swap:         4031       4031          0
Total:        7852       7816         36
```

Can anyone tell me why all the swap is in use while there is 2.8GB used for caching?  Oracle database is running on it.

Comment: Are you using Oracle Automatic Memory Mangagement (AMM)? Can you show the output of `df -h`?